# How to change Select text displayed?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of select boxes whose content is dynamically defined, the options for the second box being populated depending upon the first selection and so on. The problem I have is that once I have (for example) selected options for the first two select boxes, and then want to start again changing the first selection, the displayed text for the second box remains as it was despite my resetting the options. If I dropdown the second select box the correct (updated) options are present. Example below - you can see that on any change event, I try to set option zero of children select boxes to equal "-" in an attempt to overwrite the historically selected text, but this does not seem to work.

How can I programatically update the *displayed* select text after resetting options?

```
   <form name="capacity">
<table>
<tr><td>Type:</td>
  <td><select onchange="onchange1();" id="type">
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="Casing">Casing</option>
  <option value="Tubing">Tubing</option>
  </select></td></tr>

<tr><td>OD:</td>
    <td><select onchange="onchange2()" id="od">
    <option value="-">-</option>
    </select></td></tr>

<tr><td>Weight:</td>
  <td><select id="ppf">
    <option value="-">-</option>
      </select></td></tr></table>
```

and

```
    function onchange1() {

var type = (document.capacity.type.value);
var od = (document.capacity.od.value);
var ppf = (document.capacity.ppf.value);


document.capacity.od.options.length = 0
document.capacity.ppf.options.length = 0

document.capacity.od.options[0] = new Option("-", "-");
document.capacity.ppf.options[0] = new Option("-", "-");

if (type == "Tubing") {
    document.capacity.od.options[1] = new Option("1.05", 1.05)
    document.capacity.od.options[2] = new Option("1.315", 1.315)
    document.capacity.od.options[3] = new Option("1.66", 1.66)
}

if (type == "Casing") {
    document.capacity.od.options[1] = new Option("4.5", 4.5)
    document.capacity.od.options[2] = new Option("5", 5)
    document.capacity.od.options[3] = new Option("5.5", 5.5)
}

document.capacity.ppf.value = "-";
}

    function onchange2() {
    var type = (document.capacity.type.value);
    var od = (document.capacity.od.value);

document.capacity.ppf.options.length = 0
document.capacity.ppf.options[0] = new Option("-", "-")

if (type == "Tubing") {
    if (od == 1.05) {
        document.capacity.ppf.options[1] = new Option("1.14", 1.14)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[2] = new Option("1.2", 1.2)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[3] = new Option("1.54", 1.54)
    }
    if (od == 1.315) {
        document.capacity.ppf.options[1] = new Option("1.7", 1.7)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[2] = new Option("1.72", 1.72)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[3] = new Option("1.8", 1.8)
    }
    if (od == 1.66) {
        document.capacity.ppf.options[1] = new Option("2.1", 2.1)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[2] = new Option("2.3", 2.3)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[3] = new Option("2.33", 2.33)
    }
}

if (type == "Casing") {
    if (od == 4.5) {
        document.capacity.ppf.options[1] = new Option("9.5", 9.5)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[2] = new Option("10.5", 10.5)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[3] = new Option("11.6", 11.6)
    }
    if (od == 5) {
        document.capacity.ppf.options[1] = new Option("11.5", 11.5)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[2] = new Option("13", 13)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[3] = new Option("15", 15)
    }
    if (od == 5.5) {
        document.capacity.ppf.options[1] = new Option("14", 14)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[2] = new Option("15.5", 15.5)
        document.capacity.ppf.options[3] = new Option("17", 17)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a full demo to reproduce your problem, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Comment: And site: http://jsfiddle.net/vinomarky/xfcdF/

Comment: It actually seems to work in JSFiddle - will have so rt out why it doesnt in my case. Wonder if it has anything to do with JQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set an option use something like:

```
// by index
my_select = document.getElementById("my_select_box");
my_select.selectedIndex = 0; // set first option

// by value
var value = "my_option";
for (var i = 0; i < my_select.options.length; i += 1) {
    if (my_select.options[i].value === value) {
        my_select.selectedIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I fully expected this to be the answer, but on implementing found that it did not actually result in resetting the displaye selection for me. WIl see if I can set up a demo on JSFiddle

Comment: It actually seems to work in JSFiddle - will have sort out why it doesnt in my case. Wonder if it has anything to do with JQuery Mobile?